# Determine Top and / or Left values of the video window of Inno Media Player according to screen resolution

Tags: video, inno-setup

I wrote a code to get screen aspect ratio. Problem is that code is very long and many new screen resolutions will come in the future.
Here it is:

```pascal
function GetScreenAspectRatio(): Integer;
var
  ScreenResolution: String;
  ScreenAspectRatio: String;
begin
  ScreenResolution := IntToStr(GetSystemMetrics(0)) + 'x' + IntToStr(GetSystemMetrics(1));
  if ScreenResolution = '640x480' then ScreenAspectRatio := '4:3';
  if ScreenResolution = '800x600' then ScreenAspectRatio := '4:3';
  if ScreenResolution = '1024x768' then ScreenAspectRatio := '4:3';
  if ScreenResolution = '1152x864' then ScreenAspectRatio := '4:3';
  if ScreenResolution = '1280x960' then ScreenAspectRatio := '4:3';
  if ScreenResolution = '1400x1050' then ScreenAspectRatio := '4:3';
  if ScreenResolution = '1600x1200' then ScreenAspectRatio := '4:3';
  if ScreenResolution = '2048x1536' then ScreenAspectRatio:= '4:3';
  if ScreenResolution = '3200x2400' then ScreenAspectRatio := '4:3';
  if ScreenResolution = '4000x3000' then ScreenAspectRatio := '4:3';
  if ScreenResolution = '6400x4800' then ScreenAspectRatio := '4:3';
  if ScreenResolution = '852x480' then ScreenAspectRatio := '16:9';
  if ScreenResolution = '1024x576' then ScreenAspectRatio := '16:9';
  if ScreenResolution = '1280x1024' then ScreenAspectRatio := '5:4';
  if ScreenResolution = '1152x648' then ScreenAspectRatio := '16:9';
  if ScreenResolution = '1280x720' then ScreenAspectRatio := '16:9';
  if ScreenResolution = '1366x768' then ScreenAspectRatio := '16:9';
  if ScreenResolution = '1600x900' then ScreenAspectRatio := '16:9';
  if ScreenResolution = '1920x1080' then ScreenAspectRatio := '16:9';
  if ScreenResolution = '2560×1440' then ScreenAspectRatio := '16:9';
  if ScreenResolution = '3840x2160' then ScreenAspectRatio := '16:9';
  if ScreenResolution = '1280x800' then ScreenAspectRatio := '16:10';
  if ScreenResolution = '1440x900' then ScreenAspectRatio := '16:10';
  if ScreenResolution = '1680x1050' then ScreenAspectRatio := '16:10';
  if ScreenResolution = '1920x1200' then ScreenAspectRatio := '16:10';
  if ScreenResolution = '2560x1600' then ScreenAspectRatio := '16:10';
  if ScreenResolution = '3840x2400' then ScreenAspectRatio := '16:10';
  if ScreenResolution = '7680x4800' then ScreenAspectRatio := '16:10';
  MessageBox( WizardForm.Handle, 'Screen Aspect Ratio of Your LapTop / Computer: ' + ScreenAspectRatio, 'GetScreenAspectRatio', MB_OK or MB_ICONWARNING);
end;
```

*Message Box is for just for testing purposes. I have to use this output `ScreenAspectRatio` to determine `Top` and / or `Left` values of the video window.*

But I don't know how to determine `Top` and / or `Left` values of the video Window according to both video resolution and screen resolution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You get the dimensions of the video from the `DSInitializeVideoFile`, right? So what do you want more?

Comment: it only gets Width and Height of the Video file. when the video to be played has a small height than screen height, video window appears in the top=0. I want to make it appear center of the screen........That is the fitting video to the screen if video is smaller than screen resolution..........I need height and width of the video file to determine what value should be assigned to `Top` and / or `Left`  to Video Window to be positioned Center of the screen by using new functions `DSSetVideoWindowTop` and `DSSetVideoWindowLeft`.

Comment: So get the `Width` and `Height` returned by the `DSInitializeVideoFile` and the screen dimensions and and calculate the top/left coordinates.

Comment: There are so many screen types for many users of my program ............How can I make a decision if the screen is 4:3 or 5:4 or 16:9 or 16:10 ? How can I code to do this?

Comment: So is your question actually how to get a screen resolution?

Comment: Sorry ...........yes but not only screen resolution..........screen resolution and video resolution......and set video window's Top and / or Left according to Screen and Video Resolution Values.

Comment: Again, you have the video resolution already, right? Anyway, make sure you edit your question, to make it clear, what you want. So far your question asks for information you have already, instead of asking for what you actually need.

Comment: No I have Screen Resolution only by using `GetSystemMetrics` . but I like to have an example code to determine the Top and / or Left Values of the Video Window according to Video Resolution resturning by `DSInitializeVideoFile` and Screen Resolution.

Comment: Great, so edit your question!

Comment: Edited with a very long and Future - Incompatible Code. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just calculate a remaining space on a screen by subtracting a video dimension from a screen dimension. And divide the result by two.

```pascal
var
  Width, Height: Integer;
  Left, Top: Integer;
begin
  ...
  if DSInitializeVideoFile(..., Width, Height, ...) then
  begin
    Left := (GetSystemMetrics(0) - Width) div 2;
    Top := (GetSystemMetrics(1) - Height) div 2;
    ...
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank You! Now don't I need Aspect Ratios anymore?

Comment: No you do not need aspect ratio.

Comment: Thank you again, I will try this by testing on my multiple PCs and multiple Video Sizes, and notify you what happened.

Comment: This is a Very Useful Answer............It helped me a lot...........But I am having very small problem, it is when my video resolution is higher that my Screen Reslution `MPEGVideoHandler.Color` is showing as `clNone` even I set it to `clBtnFace` when it creates...........I only have this problem when my Video File is higher than Screen Resolution.........When Video Resolution is lower than Screen Resolution, the Colour `clBtnFace` of `MPEGVideoHandler` is showing well.......Why this happens? But I can see the `MPEGVideoHandler` is still exist when Video is larger than Screen Resolution.